# How do I delete Firestore dictionary value?

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I have a value in a document which I set like this:

```
func uploadMedDosage(dosage: String, medication: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId!)
    let updateData = ["medications" : [medication : dosage]]

    docRef.setData(updateData, merge: true) { (err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err?.localizedDescription as Any)
            self.view.makeToast(err?.localizedDescription as! String)
        } else {
            self.refresh()
            print(" Data Uploaded")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to Delete this value, but I can't figure out how:

```
func removeMedDosage(dosage: String, medication: String) {
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId!)
    let data = [[medication : dosage] : FieldValue.delete()]

    docRef.updateData(["medications" : data]) { (err) in
        print("delete")
    }
}
```

This compiles but causes a crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSSS_$ length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x2830ca100'

I've tried many different variations including

```
 let data = [[medication : dosage]]

    docRef.updateData(["medications" : FieldValue.arrayRemove(data)]) { (err) in
        print("delete")
    }
```

The data in Firestore is set like:

```
medications {
   Venlafaxine : 37.5,
   Sertraline : 100
}
```

How can I delete a [Venlafaxine : 37.5] row essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you answered your own question but I wanted to suggest there may be a more elegant solution.

There are some missing data points in the question so I will fill in with an example case - this may be of use in the overall thought process.

Let's assume your app allows patents (users) to keep track of their prescriptions. This means there would be multiple users, with each user having a prescription. That prescription has a medication and dosage.

When a user wants to delete a prescription, the code loads them all and iterates until it finds the correct one, and then deletes it. That requires iterating over the data which is really inefficient.

Let propose another method and we'll assume this is for user 0 (uid_0)

Here's what the Firestore Structure will look like

```
user_prescriptions
    uid_0
       prescriptions
          prescription_0
             medication: "some med"
             dosage: "some dosage"
          prescription_1
             medication: "some med"
             dosage: "some dosage"  
     uid_1
        prescriptions
          prescription_0
             medication: "some med"
             dosage: "some dosage"
          prescription_1
             medication: "some med"
             dosage: "some dosage"
```

when a user wants to add a medication, we call a function *uploadPrescription* and pass it the med and dosage

```
self.uploadPrescription(dosage: "100mg", medication: "Aspirin")
```

and here's the function to write that data to Firestore.

```
func uploadPrescription(dosage: String, medication: String) {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let collectionRef = db.collection("users_prescriptions").document(uid).collection("prescriptions")
    let prescriptionData = ["medication": medication,
                            "dosage": dosage]
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = collectionRef.addDocument(data: prescriptionData) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            let docJustAddedRef = ref?.documentID
            print(docJustAddedRef!)
            //maybe create a PrescriptionClass and add it to a tableview
        }

    }
}
```

the interesting thing to note is this function creates a unique child node for each prescription and captures a reference to it (that's where prescription_0 and prescription_1 id's come from).

That reference will have a documentID. This will allow each user to have an infinite number of unique prescriptions.

Then the prescription information could be shown in the UI in perhaps a tableView. The documentID is the identifier of that specific prescription and would from then on be used to remove or change the prescription information. Many times on app start, all of the prescriptions would be loaded into a class and each of those would be stored in an array used as a tableView datasource. When the user swipes to delete, you get the row they want to delete, get that prescription object from the array - remove it from the array, and then using the documentID, remove it from Firestore.

```
func removeMedDosage(documentID: String) {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let docRef = db.collection("users_scripts").document(uid).collection("prescriptions").document(documentID)
    docRef.delete()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with a dictionary, only an array. So I had to delete the whole section and rebuild it like so:

```
 func removeMedDosage(dosage: String, medication: String) {
    print("remove")
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId!)

    removeDictionary = [:]

    for (index, element) in self.meds.enumerated() {
        removeDictionary[element] = self.dosages[index]
    }

    let data = removeDictionary

    docRef.updateData(["medications" : data]) { (err) in

    }
    self.refresh()
}
```

Priot to this I deleted the chosen one from the arrays used for the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let index = indexPath.row
        let med = self.meds[index]
        let dose = self.dosages[index]

        self.meds.remove(at: index)
        self.dosages.remove(at: index)

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.removeMedDosage(dosage: dose, medication: med)

    }
    return [delete]
}
```